# How do I print only the first page in a Word document using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping someone can help me out. At work we make programs for CNC machines. these are word docs. These are saved in a folder named after the machine. i have made a userform where you can choose machine and fill in a program number. After clicking "OK" it will open all the programs needed. (this works succesfully)
I then want to print the first page of all open programs. This is where is get stuck. See code below.

```
If Len(programbox.Value) = 1 Then zeros = "00000"
If Len(programbox.Value) = 2 Then zeros = "0000"
If Len(programbox.Value) = 3 Then zeros = "000"
If Len(programbox.Value) = 4 Then zeros = "00"
If Len(programbox.Value) = 5 Then zeros = "0"
If Len(programbox.Value) = 6 Then zeros = ""

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application")
If machinebox.Value = "CTX510" Then letter = "C"
If machinebox.Value = "CTX510" Then machinebox.Value = "CTX510\program"
If machinebox.Value = "Lu25" Then letter = "F"
If machinebox.Value = "LB45" Then letter = "N"


set objdoc1 = wordapp.documents.Open "\\path\Machine\" & machinebox.Value & "\" & letter & "1" & zeros & programmabox.Value & ".OPT"
set objdoc2 = wordapp.documents.Open "\\path\Machine\" & machinebox.Value & "\" & letter & "2" & zeros & programmabox.Value & ".OPT"
set objdoc3 = wordapp.documents.Open "\\path\Machine\" & machinebox.Value & "\" & letter & "3" & zeros & programmabox.Value & ".OPT"

objdoc1.printout
objdoc2.printout
objdoc3.printout
```

this prints out the whole doc. I have searched on the internet but can't find how i can change this to only the first page.

Comment: You need to look at msdn for print out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840681.aspx , record a macro of yourself printing one from word is the easiest way to learn.  Also, the first few lines can be handled with this `zeros= string(6-Len(programbox.Value),"0")`

Comment: Thank you i will try to work with this

Comment: @Mick17 Please don't change your question and invalidate existing answers. Ask a new question instead. I rolled back your edits.

Comment: @piet.t Sorry, new to the site. I will ask a new question. Ty for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this little (untested) refactoring of your code:

```
Dim iLetter As Long
Dim letter As String
Dim objdoc As Object

Select Case machinebox.Value
    Case "CTX510"
        letter = "C"
        machinebox.Value = "CTX510\program"
    Case "Lu25"
        letter = "F"
    Case "LB45"
        letter = "N"
End Select

With CreateObject("word.application")
    For iLetter = 1 To 3
        Set objdoc = .documents.Open("\\path\Machine\" & machinebox.Value & "\" & letter & iLetter & Format(programbox.Value, "000000") & ".OPT")
        objdoc.PrintOut Pages:="1"
        objdoc.Close False
    Next iLetter
End With
```

where I:

- used `Format()` function to properly format a number from `programbox` to a 6 digits one with leading zeros
- used a `Select Case .... End Select` block to switch between different `machinebox.Value` cases
- instantiated a "temporary" Word application object
- used a loop from 1 to 3 instead of repeating three times the same statement

Comment: Thank you for this information. As a beginning programmer without any training it occurs a lot that one does things with a large detour because one simply does not know the "right" way to do it

Comment: I have integrated this into my macro. It works, but it still prints out the whole document. i have tried to change Pages:="1" to from:="1", To:="1". but this didn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: check [PrintOut()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840681.aspx) method documentation. Its describes `Pages` parameter as _The page numbers and page ranges to be printed, separated by commas_. You could try using parameters `Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="1" ,To:="1"`